# ¿Debo instalar WampServer en la pc que va a utilizar el programa?

Tags: java, mysql, wampserver

Estoy terminando de desarrollar mi primer programa (de escritorio).

Utilizo

- java
- Mysql (servidor local)
- Hibernate.

Desde un principio instalé el **WampServer** (que viene con **Mysql** como ya sabrán) y desde allí creé la base de datos, la iba modificando, además de hacer consultas para comprobar la funcionalidad de mi programa.

La pregunta es:

¿si una vez compilado el programa, o sea a la hora de llevar el archivo .jar a la pc que va a correr el programa, es esencial instalar el WampServer?.

Sospecho que lo mejor sería instalar solo el **Mysql**, pero necesito saber si, de esta forma, en el futuro podré acceder a la base de datos de esa pc (la pc de mi cliente que le vendí el programa) por fuera del programa. Necesitaría acceder en un futuro por que el programa se bloquea a los 6 meses para evitar que se distribuya jeje.. Entonces mi idea es, pasado ese tiempo, acceder a la base de datos (solo yo se la clave) y cambiar la fecha para que funcione otros 6 meses.

Entonces si le instalo solo el Mysql ¿podré acceder por fuera del programa a la base de datos?.

Además también necesitaría acceder para restaurar un respaldo (backup) de la base de datos cuando se requiera (aunque sé que esto se puede incorporar al programa).

Answer (score -1):

Si es una aplicación escritorio, no se necesita un navegador para arrancarla.
Por tanto, lo único que necesitarías es instalar el servidor MySQL.

Si necesitas acceder desde el exterior a la base de datos, necesitas instalar
en tu cliente una aplicación servidor, que esté continuamente ejecutándose.
a la espera de que te conectes desde un cliente.

En este caso tampoco es necesario WamppServer, aunque sería una posible manera.
La otra manera es que hagas una segunda aplicación que se inicie al arrancar el ordenador, y cuya misión sea permitirte modificar la base de datos desde el exterior. En ambos casos sería necesario que dejaras configurada la red de tu cliente para que el puerto de conexión esté abierto.